# Divide a string in a CSV file

Tags: regex, string, powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I have the following data in a CSV file

```
"Name","SourceIP","DestinationIP"
"Sep  1 03:55:57 mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1 03:55:57 mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1 03:55:57 mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1 03:55:57 mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
```

I need to split the `Name` column in to 3 more columns. `Date`, `Time` and `Name`. Like the following

```
"Date","Time","Name","SourceIP","DestinationIP"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
```

A bit lost on how to accomplish. I have tried this to replace the 14th character with a comma but no luck.

```
$test = import-csv C-sample.csv

$test | foreach-object {
    $_.Name = $_.Name.Replace(14, ",")
}

$test | export-csv D-sample.csv -notype
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would parse the string using a `regex` and create a new `PSCustomObject` to export it back:

```
$test = import-csv C-sample.csv
$regex = '(?<Date>\w+\s+\d{1,2})\s+(?<Time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<Name>.*)'

$test | foreach-object {
    $regMatch = [regex]::Match($_.Name, $regex)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Date = $regMatch.Groups['Date'].Value
        Time = $regMatch.Groups['Time'].Value
        Name = $regMatch.Groups['Name'].Value
        SourceIP = $_.SourceIP
        DestinationIP = $_.DestinationIP
    }
} | export-csv D-sample.csv -notype
```

---

**Regex:**

```
(?<Date>\w+\s+\d{1,2})\s+(?<Time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<Name>.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

**Output:**

```
"Date","Time","Name","SourceIP","DestinationIP"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
"Sep  1","03:55:57","mmt-5","172.16.48.158","22.22.22.22"
```

---

**Edit:**

Since you are using PowerShell 2, you can't use the `PsCustomObject` cast on a hashtable so use this instead:

```
$test = import-csv C-sample.csv
$regex = '(?<Date>\w+\s+\d{1,2})\s+(?<Time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<Name>.*)'

$test | foreach-object {
    $regMatch = [regex]::Match($_.Name, $regex)

       $object = New-Object PSObject
       Add-Member -InputObject $object -memberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value  $regMatch.Groups['Date'].Value
       Add-Member -InputObject $object -memberType NoteProperty -Name Time -Value $regMatch.Groups['Time'].Value
       Add-Member -InputObject $object -memberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $regMatch.Groups['Name'].Value
       Add-Member -InputObject $object -memberType NoteProperty -Name SourceIP -Value $_.SourceIP
       Add-Member -InputObject $object -memberType NoteProperty -Name DestinationIP -Value $_.DestinationIP
       $object
} | export-csv D-sample.csv -notype
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not getting that output. This is what I get.
`"IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Keys","Values","SyncRoot","Count"
"False","False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Object","5"
`

Comment: Did you changed anything in my script? If not, which PowerShell Version are you using?

Comment: Then you probably need to change the way how the pscustomobject is created. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. Consider to update your PowerShell version :-)